# Handle Result Type in Ajax Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I am calling an action from Jquery by Ajax call like below.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "SendSMS",
    data : data,
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    type : 'POST',
    async : true,
    success : function(res) {
        setMessage(res.stat);
    }
});
```

Because of login credentials it will not allow the action. So it should re-direct to login page. But It is not redirecting. But when I access the action directly in the URL I am getting redirected to login page.

```
http://localhost:8080/SMS/sendSMS
```

How can I handle this with jQuery?

Comment: Set up authentication and use withCredentials

Comment: I already have it. It's working fine. But the problem is when I am calling it from javascript it's not redirecting  to login page.

Comment: ajax calls don't redirect, I've edited the answer to show how the action configuration should be for that answer to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $.ajax({
    url : "SendSMS",
    data : data,
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    type : 'POST'
  }).done(function(res, textStatus, jqXHR )
      setMessage(res.stat);
  }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    if ( jqXHR.status=="403" ) {
      location.replace("login.php");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. But The first approach you mentioned I am not able to get. But the last two are not working. In my ajax call the control is not getting enter into the error function. But when I try to access I am getting valid response in the server side console.

Comment: Sorry, It's also not working. For success case the control is entering into done method. But for failure it's not

Comment: Sorry. Tried, can't. Am I doing anything wrong with the action or struts.xml?

Comment: Now it's worked. The problem I did, before this ajax call i made another ajax call. So the control went there. I added the fail and done code in that call, then it worked. Thanks.